# check if any item exist in the list (python)

Tags: python, list, loops, process, wmic

im coding a tool to get the list of windows process ... and then search for any internet browser (process name) like chrome.exe , opera.exe .... etc if found one of them then do something ... if didn't just print nothing found 
my code :

```
import os 
import time

def qa():
    home = os.environ.get("HOMEDRIVE")
    lol =home +"/"
    mycurrent = os.getcwd()
    change = os.chdir(lol)
    mycurrent = os.getcwd()



    d = os.popen("""wmic process get name | findstr /v "Name 'System Idle Process' System""").read().lower()

    lists = ["opera.exe" , "chrome.exe" , "iexplore.exe" , "firefox.exe" , "microsoftedgecp.exe"]
    for q in lists:

        if any(item in q for item in d) :


            qassam = os.popen("dir /s /b {}".format(lists[1])).read().strip()
            print qassam
            dir1 = os.path.dirname(qassam)
            print dir1


            #CreateShortCut_to_Desktop(qassam , dir1)
            print time.time()




        else:
            print "nothing found"
            break
qa()
```

i killed all the browser process and i run the code it should gives me nothing found but ... he keep loop and run this block of code :

```
 qassam = os.popen("dir /s /b {}".format(lists[1])).read().strip()
            print qassam
            dir1 = os.path.dirname(qassam)
            print dir1


            #CreateShortCut_to_Desktop(qassam , dir1)
            print time.time()
```

and this is my output :

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe C:\Program
>   Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application
>   1538829033.16 C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application
>   1538829041.34 C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application
>   1538829048.94 C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application

Comment: Can you specify what's not working? Please give an example output and it's (faulty) output, as well as the desired output.

Comment: i modify it .....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`if any(item in q for item in d) :`is not doing what you think it does.

The issue with your `if` command is that you have a `for` loop first. The `q` are the individual strings that you want to check against, so `item in q` is actually checking that the string (as the object string) is inside one of the element of the `q` string (so checking one element after the other), which cannot work. I would suggest to split each tested string to keep the filename.

Then `for item in d` is not doing what you think either. It loops one character after the other int he string as well. You may want to split the string first, so the end result could be something like:

```
d = os.popen("""wmic process get name | findstr /v "Name 'System Idle Process' System""").read().lower().split()

lists = ["opera.exe" , "chrome.exe" , "iexplore.exe" , "firefox.exe" , "microsoftedgecp.exe"]
if any(item.split(os.sep)[-1] in lists for item in d) :
```

May not be perfect, but it's a start.

Comment: not working :( it just print nothing found while my browser are running

Comment: What is not working? It's a start, you still need to check that each intermediate step does what it's supposed to do, I didn't debug it, I don't have cygwin or mays on my box.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to split the result of `os.popen(...).read()` on newlines like 'os.popen(...).read().split('\n')

That way you have a list of string, instead of one long string.

I also changed your if logic. In the future use more descriptive variable names than 'd' and 'q'. Hope this helps!

I don't have windows, so I haven't tested this.

```
import os 
import time

def qa():
    home = os.environ.get("HOMEDRIVE")
    lol =home +"/"
    mycurrent = os.getcwd()
    change = os.chdir(lol)
    mycurrent = os.getcwd()

    d = os.popen("""wmic process get name | findstr /v "Name 'System Idle Process' System""").read().lower().split('\n')
    print('proc count',len(d))

    lists = ["opera.exe" , "chrome.exe" , "iexplore.exe" , "firefox.exe" , "microsoftedgecp.exe"]
    for q in lists:

        #if any(item in q for item in d) :
        if q in d:
            print('proc',d,'browser',q)

            qassam = os.popen("dir /s /b {}".format(lists[1])).read().strip()
            print qassam
            dir1 = os.path.dirname(qassam)
            print dir1


            #CreateShortCut_to_Desktop(qassam , dir1)
            print time.time()




        else:
            print "nothing found"
            break
qa()
```